Are surjective homogeneous maps open at zero?
I'm asking this question as a follow-up inspired by this one: An open mapping theorem for homogeneous functions?
I'm actually wondering whether there exists an homogeneous map $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ that is surjective but not open at zero.
The question came up to my mind since the converse is true, i.e. an homogeneous map open at zero is clearly surjective, and I cannot find any counterexample to the counterpart of this statement up to now. I posted some time ago a related question Boundedness of the preimage of sphere via homogeneous polynomials that actually constituted the main hole towards a proof of this fact.
As a matter of fact it is fairly easy to prove that an homogeneous map open at zero that has non trivial zeros is surjective, but I feel that this assumption is too restrictive: at least in the case of quadratic maps it is proved here in Lemma 2 that if $n$ is big enough then surjectivity implies the existence of nontrivial zeros.
Thanks in advance for any kind of help.
Gil

Do you mean positively homogeneous, i.e., $f(tx)=tf(x)$ for $t>0$, or fully homogeneous, i.e., the above equality for all $t\in\mathbb R$?

@JochenWengenroth fully homogeneous

ok then I'll change the example accordingly

Consider the set $$Q:=\Big(B\big((0,0),1\big)\setminus(0,\infty)^2\Big)\cup B\big((\frac12,0),\frac12\big)\subset \mathbb R^2.$$
(Three quarters of an Euclidean disk of radius one, plus one half of an Euclidean disk of radius one half). Note that it  is a star-shaped set, it is not a neighbourhood of the origin, but its trace on every line through the origin, is a relative neighbourhood of the origin, so that $\bigcup_{t>0}tQ=\mathbb R^2$.  The boundary of $Q$ is a simple closed curve, so we can choose a parametrisation $\partial B(0,1)\to \partial Q$ and extend it to a homogeneous map $f:\mathbb R^2\to  \mathbb R^2$. Then $f$ is continuous, positively homogeneous, surjective, not open at the origin.
For a fully homogeneous map, one may replace $Q$ with the symmetric set
$$R :=\{(x,y)\in B((0,0),1), xy\le0\}\cup B((1/2,0),1/2)\cup B((-1/2,0),1/2)), $$
whose boundary is a symmetric closed figure-eight curve, and extend an odd parametrisation of the boundary it to a fully  $1$-homogeneous map.
Hints for a possible polynomial example
Consider a symmetric curve  $S$ like this

That is the set  $[0,1] \cdot S$, like the above set $R$,  is not a nbd of the origin, yet $\mathbb R \cdot S$ is the whole plane $\mathbb R^2$. If we can make such a symmetric curve $S$ by a Cartesian parametrisation on $[0,2\pi]$ given by two trigonometric polynomials, $X(t)=P(\cos t,\sin t ),$ $Y(t)=Q(\cos t,\sin t)$, where $P(x,y)$, $Q(x,y)$ are homogeneous polynomials of the same degree (in fact it would be sufficient they have all their terms of even degree, or all terms of odd degree, since we may multiply each term by some power of $x^2+y^2$), then  the map $(x,y)\mapsto (P(x,y), Q(x,y))$ would be a surjective non-open homogeneous polynomial map $f$ such that $f(\partial B(0,1)=S$.
Note that for a mop $f$ of even degree, it is not required that $S$ be symmetric.

Thanks for the prompt reply, let me take some time to digest it even though I think I grasped the idea already. Do you think you can come up with a polynomial map as well or is that case essentially different?

To extend a continuous function $\varphi:\partial B(0,1) \to \mathbb R^2$ to a (fully) homogeneous function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$, an obvious necessary condition is $\varphi(-x)=-\varphi(x)$. I thus do not understand how to extend the parametrization.

In your first set, you might need to say $B((0,0),1) \setminus (0,\infty)^2$ so that it still includes an interval on the positive vertical axis.

thank you, fixed

Actually  now I’m not sure that the above  idea for a  homogeneous polynomial example may work …

@JochenWengenroth Actually the OP doesn't ask for a given degree of homogeneity; $\varphi(-x)=-\varphi(x)$ is a necessary (and sufficient) condition to extend $\varphi:\partial B(0,1)\to\mathbb R^2$ to a (fully) homogeneous map of odd degree; for even degree the condition would be $\varphi(-x)=\varphi(x)$ (which I think may be easier do get with a polynomial map).

@PietroMajer what is not convincing you for the polynomial example?

I tried to make these parametrizations  explicit, and every time I get homogeneous polynomials P(x,y) and Q(x,y) with different degrees (different parity)...

Another point not immediately clear to me. Would your function have non trivial zeroes? From the drawing it is not clear but of course it might just be because i cannot figure out the parametrization

Yes, given an odd $\varphi:\partial  B\to \mathbb R^2$  with a zero $x_0$, $\varphi(x_0)=0$, the   extension $f(x):=|x|\varphi(x/|x| )$  vanishes on the line $\mathbb  Rx_0.$  In the picture, the  zeros of $\varphi$  should be two points on the unit circle,  so the zero set of $f$  should  be two lines.

Thinking better I realized that this is doable. For the constuction of a counterexample, things are easier with maps of even degree both in $x$ and in $ y$, since they will map the unit circle  to an arc. I wrote the construction here since the question was explicitly on homogeneous polynomial maps https://mathoverflow.net/questions/477058/boundedness-of-the-preimage-of-sphere-via-homogeneous-polynomials/479696#479696
