When a surjective homogeneous polynomial map is not open at the origin
Question(s):
Do  there exist surjective homogeneous polynomial maps $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ (A) of odd degree less than $5$, and (B) of even degree less than $8$, such that the origin is not interior to the image of the disk?
This is a follow-up of a series of question on the same theme raised by users charlestoncrabb and Gil Sanders (linked below).
The reason of the above bounds on the degree is the that now I know a couple of examples of such maps, of degree $5$ and $8$ (and of course multiplying them by some power of $x^2+y^2$ one also has examples of every odd degree $d\ge5$, and even degree $d\ge 8$). So it remains the curiosity about the remaining cases. Are there examples of lower degree? I tend to think the answer to both question is no, because, for a homogeneous map, sending the disk to a set that has the origin on its boundary, and still absorbs the whole plane, requires bending it quite a lot, which for polynomial maps requires higher degree.
Bonus question (C): What about maps $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$?
An open mapping theorem for homogeneous functions?
Are surjective homogeneous maps open at zero?
Boundedness of the preimage of sphere via homogeneous polynomials
